# How to add an increment(1) to the value of an element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, auto-increment

```
<span id="shortfall" style="color:black">$row[shortfall]</span>
```

How to increase $row[shortfall] to $row[shortfall]+1 with JQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need `parseInt` to handle strings as numbers.

```
$("#shortfall").text(parseInt($("#shortfall").text()) + 1);
```

Comment: That could cause some confusion if the initial value is, say, "077": parseInt("077")+1 = 64.

Comment: How did you determine it was an integer?  What if it is a decimal?  parseInt( "0.34" ) = 0

Comment: @tvanfosson: Then just use `parseDouble`? =) I however do not expect that the values are all doubles if he ask to increment the value with 1, so I consider that comment very nitpicky.

Comment: @BalusC: No-one deliberately uses octals. But people could accidentally use them.

Comment: One should always use the _radix_ parameter when calling `parseInt()` to prevent potential problems, such as the octal issue. `$("#shortfall").text(parseInt($("#shortfall").text(), 10) + 1);`

Answer (score 2):

By the time it gets to the browser, your expression will have been evaluated and turned into a number.  To use jQuery you'd simply get the text value of the span, convert it to a number, then replace the text value.  You will need to convert the value to a number before doing the addition or it will do string concatenation.

```
$("#shortfall").each( function() {
    $(this).text( Number($(this).text()) + 1 );
});
```

**Updated**: I'm using each to show how you would do this using a generic selector that might accept a collection of inputs.  In your case, if you know it matches exactly one element, you might optimize it at the risk of having to rewrite it if you wanted the code to apply to multiple elements.

```
var span = $("#shortfall");
span.text( Number( span.text() ) + 1 );
```

**Updated**: need to use text() (or html()) since the element is a SPAN, not an input.

Comment: what is this each() function for? There's only one of it.

Comment: I think the value can only be obtained by $('#shortfall).attr('value');

Comment: @Steven: no, by text(). It is not an attribute, but just the body.

Comment: @BalusC - it's more general to assume that the selector results in a collection.  If it does, then you don't want to use text which will aggregate the innerText of all the matched elements.  Using the each function allows the code to still work if the selector is changed to match multiple elements.

Comment: @tvanfosson: The problem lies somewhere else if the ID (yes, the identifier) selector returns more than one element.

Comment: @BalusC -- my point was that if you change the selector, my code still works as is.  It is, therefore, more general because it recognizes that jQuery returns a collection of objects.  Your code assumes that the collection only has one element because of the semantics of the selector.  It's personal preference and I've updated to show the alternative, but I choose to make my code more robust initially with respect to the selector.

Comment: @tvanfosson: sure it may be a good practice. But it should already at design level be spotted whether the element in question is unique or not. If so, use id. If not, use class. The jQuery only comes hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#increment").click(function(){
    $(".sl-no").html(function(){
      $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html())+1);
    }); 
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button id='increment'>Click to Increment</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sl</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>1</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>2</td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>3</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>4</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>5</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='sl-no'>6</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.